# Confusion in understanding (char *) &((struct name *)0)->member)

Tags: c, pointers

```
(struct name *)0
```

Is it creating pointer with name zero that points to struct? Or is it some pointer that points to struct and says that let's assume address of struct is zero? If so what is the name of this pointer and how to access it later on?

```
(char *) &((struct name *)0)->member)
```

This casts the address of `member` to `char *`. What does that mean? Is it taking address of `member` and transforming it into a `char` pointer? And as a result this `char` pointer points to `member`? What is the name of this `char` type pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `(char *) &((struct name *)0)->member) - 0`?

If so, somebody inlined `offsetof`. It's better to treat this is as irreducable. Use the header `stddef.h` and the macro `offsetof`.

This breaks down as follows. `(struct name *)0` is a null pointer of type `struct name*`; dereferencing it with `->member` results in a deference of the struct at that offset; except not really because `&` goes "oh nevermind, just give me the address instead`. Then we cast that to` char *`(because it's size is 1) thus resulting in the byte pointer to member, and subtracting 0 is pointer arithmatic to convert that to a number of`ptrdiff_t` size. So you're left with the offset of the member in the structure. Only I'm told it doesn't always work.

Just use the macro. The compiler guys figured it out so you don't have to.